# Sending Complete JSON Data from the CSV file in one request in JMeter

Tags: json, csv, request, jmeter

I'm trying to send a JSON request in JMeter

`{"responseProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON","requestProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON","codes":"164","122","123","161","149","158"]}`

Instead of hardcoding the values i tried saving them in a CSV file and looping through them.I tried using CSV data set config to loop,but the request is being sent this way

```
{"responseProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON","requestProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON", "codes":"164"}

{"responseProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON","requestProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON", "codes":"122"}

{"responseProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON","requestProtocol":"PROTOCOL_JSON", "codes":"123"}
```

It is sending one code for each request and sending multiple request while looping through the end of file.

Is there a way to send multiple codes in a single request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently JMeter doesn't provide a relevant test element or even a combination of test elements to implement your scenario so you'll have to bypass this JMeter limitation by some scripting.

Given that your CSV file looks like:

```
164
122
123
161
149
158
```

And you're using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to send JSON via POST method, you can do it as follows:

1. Add a [Beanshell Preprocessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) **as a child** of the HTTP Request sampler, which should send that JSON data
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   StringBuilder requestBody = new StringBuilder();

   requestBody.append("{\"responseProtocol\":\"PROTOCOL_JSON\",\"requestProtocol\":\"PROTOCOL_JSON\",\"codes\":[");

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/your/csv/file.csv")));
   String line;

   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

       requestBody.append("\"").append(line).append("\"").append(",");

   }

   reader.close();

   requestBody.append("]}");
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("",requestBody.toString(),"");
   ```
3. Replace `/path/to/your/csv/file.csv` with the real path to your CSV file
4. Populate sampler configuration like host, port, path. **Do not put anything into 
   "Parameters" or "Body Data"**

That should be it. Run test with 1 thread and look into [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to ensure that everything is fine.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](http://How%20to%20Use%20BeanShell:%20JMeter's%20Favorite%20Built-in%20Component) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter and a kind of cookbook with some popular Beanshell script recipes.

Comment: after a bit of digging through the manuals and trying your script it worked.